# Object spread not working in Node 7.5

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-node

```
// Rest properties
require("babel-core").transform("code", {
  plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
});

let { x, y, ...z } = { x: 1, y: 2, a: 3, b: 4 };
console.log(x); // 1
console.log(y); // 2
console.log(z); // { a: 3, b: 4 }

// Spread properties
let n = { x, y, ...z };
console.log(n); // { x: 1, y: 2, a: 3, b: 4 }
```

I am trying the above example from http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/ and it's not working.

```
let { x, y, ...z } = { x: 1, y: 2, a: 3, b: 4 };
            ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

If I run it with `babel-node` then it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: You cannot put your babel call in the same file as the code with the experimental features?! For babel-node, you put that plugin in the configuration file

Comment: so how should I structure this? if this is my index.js

Comment: You say it works fine when run with babel-node. So what is your aim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require("babel-core").transform("code", {
  plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
});
```

This is the Node API to transform code given as the first argument of the `.transform()` function. You would need to replace `"code"` with the actual code you want to transform. It won't touch any files. You don't do anything with the returned code, but you try to run the rest of the file regularly with Node, which doesn't support object spread operator yet. You would either have to execute the generated code, or write it to a file, which you can run with Node.

Here is an example how you would transpile your code with the Node API:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
const fs = require('fs');

// Code that will be transpiled
const code = `let { x, y, ...z } = { x: 1, y: 2, a: 3, b: 4 };
console.log(x); // 1
console.log(y); // 2
console.log(z); // { a: 3, b: 4 }

// Spread properties
let n = { x, y, ...z };
console.log(n); // { x: 1, y: 2, a: 3, b: 4 }`

const transformed = babel.transform(code, {
  plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
});

// Write transpiled code to output.js
fs.writeFileSync('output.js', transformed.code);
```

After running this, you have a file `output.js` which transformed the object spread. And then you could run it with:

```
node output.js
```

See also [babel.transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/core-packages/#babel-transform-code-string-options-object-).

You're probably not going to use the Node API, unless you want to do some very specific with the code, which is some sort of analysis or transformation, but certainly not running it. Or of course when you integrate it in a tool that needs to transpile the code programmatically.

If you want to just run code, use [`babel-node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node). If you want to just transpile it, use the [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel) executable.

Answer (score 0):

You may check [Node.js ES2015 Support](http://node.green/). Nodejs `object rest/spread properties` is supported form [v8.3](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/).

```
let person = {id:1, name: 'Mahbub'};
let developer = {...person, type: 'nodeJs'};
let {name, ...other} = {...developer};

console.log(developer); // --> { id: 1, name: 'Mahbub', type: 'nodeJs' } 
console.log(name); // --> Mahbub
console.log(other); // --> { id: 1, type: 'nodeJs' }
```